# How to create .snk file for Mono android

Tags: monodevelop, snk

I have done android project in the mono develop It working fine in debug mode but when I am Trying to run project in release mode then it is giving following error:

```
C:\Users\Administrator.EDZ0138\Documents\Projects\IdooctopusNew\IdooctopusNew\SGEN: Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c4c4237547e4b6cd' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A) (IdooctopusNew)
```

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution for this issue.

You just have to do is, put the `mono.android.dll` in to the `C:\Program
Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin` folder, open a command prompt and do
following steps:

1. `cd C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin`
2. `sn -Vr Mono.Android.dll`
3. `gacutil -i C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin`

Then build the project.

If you get the error for another DLL like `System.xml.dll` etc. then repeat above
procedure for respective DLL.

All the best.......!