# Monogame project won't compile release build

Tags: android, xamarin.android, monogame

I have a MonoGame android project that I have created. Everything worked fine and debug still builds, but when I try and build a release version of the game I get this error:

```
Error 1 Could not load file or assembly 'Mono.Android, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=c4c4237547e4b6cd' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed.
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A) C:\Users\Dominick\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\AndroidPong\AndroidPong\SGEN
AndroidPong
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have looked around but I haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many SO posts describing the same problem. Check out the following links:

- [Add Assembly to GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14197563/1108036)
- [Error building a Release version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5792193/1108036)

Comment: I have tried both those responses and neither of them seemed to help.

Comment: Ok, did you try to turn off the option `Generate serialization assembly` in the project settings?